# React Hooks - Retry Failed Async Requests Inside of useEffect that is Dependent on Props

Tags: reactjs

Does anybody know what patterns are considered best practice when it comes to retrying `async` network requests that fail within a `useEffect` hook? I have the following component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react'
import styles from './_styles.module.scss'

type Props = {
  itemIds: string[];
}

function MyComponent({itemIds}: Props): JSX.Element {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const [itemsData, setItemsData] = useState<Record<string, Item>>({})

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchItemsData() {
      setError(false)
      const {data, error: fetchError} = await getDataForItems(itemIds) // uses fetch API under the hood

      if (fetchError) {
        setError(true)
        setLoading(false)
        return
      }

      setItemsData(data)
      setLoading(false)
    }

    if (loading) {
      void fetchItemsData()
    }
  }, [itemIds, loading])

  const retry = useCallback(() => {
    setLoading(true)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {loading && (
        <div className={styles.loadingSpinner} />
      )}
      {(!loading && error) && (
        <div>
          <div>Some error message with a try again button</div>
          <button onClick={retry}>Try Again</div>
        </div>
      )}
      {(!loading && !error) && (
        <div>Success</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The intent is for this component to be re-usable, and I have the `useEffect` hook configured to trigger in the event the `itemIds` prop changes or if the `loading` state changes. I have that `loading` state to help display loading-based visuals but also to serve as the retry request mechanism. The problem with this, however, is I have to guard the execution of the `fetchItemsData` function using that flag to prevent the effect from running that request again after every `setLoading` invocation.

Furthermore, in the event the initial request succeeds (`loading` will be set to `false`), when the `itemIds` prop updates to a new set of ids, the effect will not fire off because `loading` is `false` which prevents the execution of the `fetchItemsData` function.

Does anyone have a good pattern for handling request retries like this in React Hooks?